Pod of StatefulSet is terminated and stays in Status Completed
Introduction
I've an issue with a pod in a StatefulSet which is terminated, stays in the Completed state and is not restarted.
I will describe the situation in a concrete example, that will provide some status and log data to analyze the issue.
Background: Our Installation
We run a mongodb 7.0.7 aks kubernetes cluster using a StatefulSet
Analysis
In the status section of the pod's yaml (see below) I can see that the pod was terminated with status code 0, but I can't see a reason, why the pod isn't restarted. Of course we have restartPolicy: Always
In the kubelet logs (also below) I can see that the pod was evicted (because of NodeHasInsufficientMemory).
My understanding of kubernetes is, that the pod

should be always rescheduled, so that the StatefulSet has the desired count of healthy pods.
remains in Pending state as long as not enough resources are available
the pod will be created as soon as enough resources are available

Question

Is my understanding correct?
So why isn't the pod rescheduled?
Which kubernetes process should care about the rescheduling?
Can I find more logs about rescheduling?

Status YAML
status:
  conditions:
  ...
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-30T23:48:10Z"
    reason: PodCompleted
    status: "False"
    type: Ready
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2024-04-30T23:48:10Z"
    reason: PodCompleted
    status: "False"
    type: ContainersReady
  ...
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: containerd://12345
    image: mongodb:7.0.7
    imageID: mongodb@sha256:12345
    lastState: {}
    name: mongodb
    ready: false
    restartCount: 0
    started: false
    state:
      terminated:
        containerID: containerd://123345
        exitCode: 0
        finishedAt: "2024-04-30T23:48:09Z"
        reason: Completed
        startedAt: "2024-04-24T17:55:38Z"

Kubelet Log
kubectl debug node/mynode -it --image=busybox
 
chroot /host
journalctl -u kubelet -o cat|grep mongodb

...
... kuberuntime_container.go ... : "Killing container with a grace period" pod="mongodb-0" ...
...  eviction_manager.go:427] "Eviction manager: pods successfully cleaned up" pods=[mongodb-0]


Yes your understanding is correct,lack of enough resources is an issue which is stopping rescheduling of pod,
Kubernetes scheduler handles the responsibility of rescheduling.

Refer to this blog by Ismail Ajagbe for  more insights of kubelet logs.

I think I've to check the scheduler log which
is located in the control plane: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/#control-plane-nodes
Unfortunately I can't access the control-plance in aks. Need to activate azure logging.
